# Apply style in parent components to child components

Tags: angular

I have some components that were coded by other people. Now I want to use these components in my app.
At this time, I'd like to modify their styles.
Generally, how to apply style in parent components (mine) to child components (not mine)?

**Common component's Template**：

```
<span class="input-text" >
  <span *ngIf="isRequired" class="required-mark">※</span>
<input #nativeElement
       class="{{class}}"
       ...
>
</span>
```

**My component's Template(host)**：

```
<common-input-text class="my-input-class" ...></common-input-text>
```

**My component's css**：

```
.my-input-class {
  background-color:blue;
  width: 400px;
}
```

`my-input-class` won't be used to the `common-input-text` component.

If I defined `my-input-class` at `styles.css` file, it would work. But I don't think it's a good way. Because it affects all pages.

**One solution**:
Using the following css definition in my component css file can achieve it.

```
:host /deep/ input {
  background-color: red;
  width: 300px;
}
```

But, is it a good idea?
Every time I want to adjust the child component slightly, I have to do it like this. I think Angular must have better ways to achieve this.

Comment: Add `display: block`to the my-input-class class definition. http://plnkr.co/edit/QNuMA2LRUM5j5dXPiVyw?p=preview

Comment: @JBNizet Actually, I want to apply `my-input-class` class only to `input`, not that whole common component.

Comment: Why do you think applying a CSS class to the whole child component should apply it to the input it contains?

Comment: It's my purpose. I don't know how to achieve it.

Comment: The child component can't possibly use a CSS class that is not defined in its own styles, or globally.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148109/discussion-between-niaomingjian-and-jb-nizet).